# Room reservation Exchange <> Sharepoint Online (Office 365)

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, office-365, resources

Is it possible to create a room reservation in a calendar on Sharepoint Online?
If so, how can this be done?

Also, Is it possible to add resources (like projectors,...) without adding them as a room?
(maybe this second one is more an exchange question...)
But I would need it also from exchange as an extra column in my sharepoint form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used [Exchange Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) for building the reservation system. I have developed the similar reservation system using SharePoint 2007 and Exchange Server 2010

You can add all you resources, rooms, projectors and book them very easily. You might need to fix some permissions on resources like FreeBusy information etc. etc.

[How to configure the Resource/Rooms etc](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-server-2010-room-mailboxes-step-by-step-guide)

[Introduction to EWS Managed API with examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Comment: And this won't be a problem if I'm using Office 365? + Do you know where to find some tutorials/examples? Thanks!

Comment: I have never used Office 365 but it should be no different to configure a Resource than in Exchange 2010.

Answer (score -1):

use the link below

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-0bdb58b9-db48-4c9f-b3f4-b2052f0576bc[enter link description here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-0bdb58b9-db48-4c9f-b3f4-b2052f0576bc)

Comment: The link indicates the functionality is deprecated.  Have you tried this on SharePoint online?